# How to convert my Chrome app to extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I have created a Chrome app, but I found that uploading it to Chrome Web Store is problematic, as they declare it is only compatible with Chrome OS.

There is a tutorial by Google how to move to web applications, but I find it unusable. 
I would like to publish it as an extension, so the sensible move I think is using a Chrome extension, not a Chrome app. Still, I am not sure what what's the best next step.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on which API your app is using. Some of those aren't available in extensions, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). Other than that, it's a straightforward task.

Comment: thanks. And when I create an extension, it's supported for upload to the web store without the same limitations?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by that. An extension is a different thing, not related to chrome apps.

Comment: @wOxxOm not sure of how straightforward it is, since no howto appears anywhere online and this very question has never been answered. Why do you think it is straightforward? Could you send any source that may prove this? Many thanks

Comment: Ask a new question with [MCVE](/help/mcve) and info about the specific problems.